# How are shared library dependency paths determined on Linux?

Tags: linux, gcc, dependencies, shared-libraries, ldd

When I run `ldd` against a shared library such as `libphp5.so` I see that it has a dependency on `libmysqlclient.so.16`:

```
$ ldd ./libphp5.so
libmysqlclient.so.16 => /usr/lib/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.16 
[other dependencies snipped out]
```

Are these dependency filenames and paths (`/usr/lib/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.16`) baked into the shared library binary? Or is this path determined by some other means such as via `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/mysql-i386.conf`, which incidentally contains:

```
/usr/lib/mysql/
```

One other thing is puzzling me:

There is a shared library I have that I compile from source. This has a dependency on `libmysqlclient_r`. The `gcc` compiler switches to produce this this library look like:

```
gcc -shared -L/usr/lib/mysql -lmysqlclient_r [+various other switches]
```

When I do `ldd mylib.so` I see:

```
libmysqlclient_r.so.16 => /usr/lib/mysql/libmysqlclient_r.so.16 (0x0055c000)
```

However in the `/usr/lib/mysql` directory I see:

```
-rwxr-xr-x. libmysqlclient_r.so -> libmysqlclient_r.so.16.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx. libmysqlclient_r.so.16 -> libmysqlclient_r.so.16.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x. libmysqlclient_r.so.16.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx. libmysqlclient.so -> libmysqlclient.so.16.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx. libmysqlclient.so.16 -> libmysqlclient.so.16.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x. libmysqlclient.so.16.0.0
```

`libmysqlclient_r.so` is a symbolic link to `libmysqlclient_r.so.16.0.0`, so why does `ldd` show the dependency as `libmysqlclient_r.so.16`. Is there some magic I'm missing here?

<sub>Having been a Windows dev for many years I'm a bit new to `gcc` and development on Linux.</sub>

My Linux distribution is CentOS 6.0 x86-32bit.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can see which paths are coming from where by running

```
LD_DEBUG=libs ldd ./libphp5.so
```

> Are these dependency filenames and paths (/usr/lib/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.16) baked into the shared library binary?

The filename almost certainly is. The path usually isn't. You can see what is baked into the binary with

```
readelf -d ./libphp5.so
```

Look for `(NEEDED)` and `(RPATH)` entries.

Also give `man ld.so` a read. There are many factors that affect how dynamic loader searches for shared libraries: `ld.so.conf`, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, whether the executable is `suid` or not, how glibc was configured, which `-rpath` settings were given at link time, etc. etc.

Comment: You have no idea, but I wish I could upvote this even more. My question stemmed from being unable to load `libmysqlclient_r` used in a Python cheese shop package (MySQL-Python) despite it compiling/building just fine. `LD_DEBUG=libs ldd` was my life safer. It transpires that the path file saved in  `/etc/ld.co.conf.d` didn't end in `.conf` and my `/etc/ld.so.conf` file specifies: `include ld.so.conf.d/*.conf`. So the `/usr/lib/mysql` folder was never being searched.

Answer (score 1):

> Are these dependency filenames and paths (/usr/lib/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.16) baked into the shared library binary?

Yes, they can be and often are. The keyword here is `-rpath`. However, ld.conf also has its say. The whole system is quite complex, unfortunately.